# Android and iOS compatible audio only ad networks

Tags: mobile, advertising

I am developing an Android and iOS app with primarily audio based content. The app will be monetized with audio ads which play before the content. The users will most likely be listening to our content with their phone screen locked so banner and video ads will not work. I am looking for recommendations for an ad network, similar to AdMob, which will allow me to play their audio ads on my app. Preferably one which has SDK libraries for both Android and iOS.